# Substitution in renaming file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help with the following:

I have these files with names: `ABC.rt1, ABC.rt2, ... , ABC.rt8`

I should rename all of them in the following way: if the number, let us say `i` at the end `.rt${i}` is odd, then replace the extension by appendig AB, else CD. For example I would expect these output:

`ABC.rt1` --> `ABC.rt1-AB`

`ABC.rt2` --> `ABC.rt1-CD` ... etc.

I tried to use this simple script, but does not work:

```
for i in `seq 1 8`; do mv -v ./ABC.rt${i} ./ABC.rt${if [ $(( $i % 2 )) -eq 0 ] ; then echo ${i}-CD; else echo ${i}-AB;fi};done
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean `ABC.rt2` --> `ABC.rt2-CD`? (As opposed to `rt1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in `seq 1 8`; do
  if [ $(( $i % 2 )) -eq 0 ] ; then
    newext=${i}-CD
  else
    newext=${i}-AB
  fi
  mv -v ./ABC.rt${i} ./ABC.rt$newext
done
```

Don't try and cram all that in a single line, it's unreadable and your syntax ends up being incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific example it might be easier to make two loops?

```
for i in *[1357];do mv -v $i $i-AB;done
for i in *[2468];do mv -v $i $i-CD;done
```

If its a requirement to create a general solution please let me know and I'll help more.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e'while(<*.rt?>) { rename $_, $_.($1 % 2 ? "-AB" : "-CD") if /\.rt(\d)$/ }'
```

Before:

```
a.rt1  a.rt2
```

After:

```
a.rt1-AB  a.rt2-CD
```

Note: it is different from the example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, all bash, short and concise:

```
for f in *[1-8]
do
    mv $f $f-`echo $f | grep -q '[1357]$' && echo AB || echo CD`
done
```